# Continuous convex function

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Suppose function $f:[0,1]\mapsto R$ is twice continuously differentiable and satisfies $f(0)>0$, $f(1)<0$ and $f''>0$. Does equation $f(x) = 0$ have a unique solution on $[0,1]$?

Here is my own proof:

Suppose there exist two solutions $x_1,x_2\in(0,1)$ and $x_1\neq x_2$. Then by convexity of $f$,
$$f(\alpha x_1+(1-\alpha)x_2)<\alpha f(x_1)+(1-\alpha)f(x_2)=0$$
for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Pick an arbitrary $x_0 \in (x_1,x_2)$, we have $f(x_0)<0$. Again, by convexity,
$$f(\beta x_0+(1-\beta)1)<\beta f(x_0)+(1-\beta)f(1)<0$$
for any $\beta\in(x_0,1)$. This implies that $f(x)<0$ for any $x\in(x_0,1)$, which contradicts that $x_2\in(x_0,1)$, $f(x_2)=0$.

Comment: You would think this is true, right? The way to do it would be to contradict the existence of two real roots.

Comment: Yes, if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ for some $0 \le x_1 < x_2 \le 1$ then $f(x) \ge f(x_1) = 0$ for all $ x \in [0,1]$ which would contradict $f $ being convex and $f(1) < 0$.

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu Can you use copper.hat's suggestion to finish? Remember that $f'' >0$ implies that once $f'$ is zero, it is always going to increase from that point on. Between two real roots of $f$ lies a real root of $f'$ by Rolle. But once $f'$ becomes zero, it starts increasing from that point on so $f$ could never really have come down from the point where $f'$ became zero. Translate this to a mathematical proof.

Comment: I added my proof.